# transliteration is not being done automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, transliteration

I am using the below posted code to `transliterate` the input from English to Urdu and Arabic. The transliteration should be done automatically when I hit enter button inside the input field (English text), but that is not happening. However, if I manually hit enter button inside Urdu and Arabic fields then their text is being transliterated. But please tell how can I get the desired behavior i.e. the input text should automatically be transliterated inside Urdu an Arabic fields when I hit enter button inside English field?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Google Transliterate API
    google.load("elements", "1", {
      packages: "transliteration"
    });

    function onLoad() {
      var options_u = {
        sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.URDU],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
      };

      var options_a = {
        sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ARABIC],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
      };

      // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
      // options.
      var control_u = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options_u);
      var control_a = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options_a);

      control_u.makeTransliteratable(['txtUrdu']);
      control_a.makeTransliteratable(['txtArabic']);

      $("#txtEnglish").on('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          $("#txtUrdu").val($("#txtEnglish").val());
          $("#txtUrdu").focus();
          $("#txtUrdu").trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', {
            keyCode: 13
          }));

          $("#txtArabic").val($("#txtEnglish").val());
          $("#txtArabic").focus();
          $("#txtArabic").trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', {
            keyCode: 13
          }));
        }
      });
    } //end onLoad function

    google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  English: <input type="text" id="txtEnglish" /> <br/> Urdu: <input type="text" id="txtUrdu" /><br/> Arabic: <input type="text" id="txtArabic" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your example works fine for me on Chrome - I enter Text in the English Box and hit enter once, the other two fields are filled. What browser were you testing this with?

Comment: @Sirence, the other two field are filled but are not transliterated i.e. they are not showing the text in urdu and arabic respectively

Comment: Arabic does look translated to me, at least the field reads 'تست' if I put in 'test' in english. But Urdu is indeed still test.

Comment: so please tell the solution for urdu

Comment: I'd say you should change your whole approach, at the moment, you copy the english text to the two other boxes then call translate on them. Instead you should just translate the text then fill the boxes with the translations, to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: how can i do that, can you please write the piece of code for that?